# YARN - application not getting accepted, error code 125

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a spark-submit to yarn, but the application first hangs in ACCEPTED state, then fails with the following error:

```
22/11/23 17:58:24 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:24 INFO yarn.Client:
         client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service:  }
         diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: root.users.my_user
         start time: 1669222703023
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: https://mask:8090/proxy/application_1668608030982_2921/
         user: my_user
22/11/23 17:58:25 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:26 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:27 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:28 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:29 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:30 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:31 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:32 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:33 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:34 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:35 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:36 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:37 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:38 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:39 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:40 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:41 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:42 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:43 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/11/23 17:58:44 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1668608030982_2921 (state: FAILED)
22/11/23 17:58:44 INFO yarn.Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: Application application_1668608030982_2921 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1668608030982_2921_000002 exited with  exitCode: 125
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-11-23 17:58:43.566]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e172_1668608030982_2921_02_000001
Exit code: 125
Exception message: Launch container failed
Shell output: main : command provided 1
main : run as user is my_user
main : requested yarn user is my_user
Getting exit code file...
Creating script paths...
Writing pid file...
Writing to tmp file /var/SP/data12/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1668608030982_2921/container_e172_1668608030982_2921_02_000001/container_e172_1668608030982_2921_02_000001.pid.tmp
Writing to cgroup task files...
Creating local dirs...
Launching container...
```

I cannot find any references to exit code 125 for yarn; Any idea why this fails?
deploy mode is cluster

this is the spark-submit with a mock class name and without app params at the end(they are verified to be good parameters):

```
nohup spark-submit\
        --class com.myClass\
        --master yarn\
        --deploy-mode $DEPLOY_MODE\
        --num-executors $NUM_EXEC\
        --executor-memory $EXEC_MEM\
        --executor-cores $NUM_CORES\
        --driver-memory "2g"\
        --jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar\
        --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-driver.properties -Dvm.logging.level=$DRIVER_LOGLEVEL -Dvm.logging.name=$LOGGING_NAME"\
        --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-executor.properties -Dvm.logging.level=$EXECUTOR_LOGLEVEL -Dvm.logging.name=$LOGGING_NAME"\
        --files "log4j-driver.properties,log4j-executor.properties"\
        --conf spark.yarn.keytab=$KRB_KEYTAB\
        --conf spark.yarn.principal=$KRB_PRINCIPAL\
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false\
        --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=in-memory\
        --conf spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true\
        $JAR
```

Comment: how much memory where you trying to allocate?  Was the cluster busy at the time?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from the application container log for container_e172_1668608030982_2921_02_000001 ?
You will need to login to the node it ran on to look at the log.

Comment: 125 isn't a 'standard' error code which likely means that one of the services supporting yarn threw an error.

Comment: @MattAndruff unfortunately, I don't have the access to the exact cluster at the moment(I will try to find it tomorrow), however it was able to start apps the with the same configuration using a json curl from the same machine. The memory is not a problem, I am using around 25% of the cluster, which was at 0% utilization at the time

Comment: You'll still need to gather the real logs from `tracking URL`, or use `yarn` cli to get the same